# wxWidgets transparent frame with opaque controls

Tags: visual-c++, wxwidgets

I've a frame with wxStaticBitmap when i make the frame semi-transparent using wxTopLevelWindow::SetTransparent(), staticbitmap also gets transparent. 
Is there a way we can make only the frame transparent and not the controls?.
(similar to windows 7 taskbar and startmenu).

Thanks in advance,

Have a nice day! 
Rajan.M

Comment: Does whatever you put in your wxStaticBitmap have a mask, and have you tried making it so there are no transparent pixels? Have you tried calling `wxWindow::SetTransparent()` on your controls?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a panel fitted to the frame's client area and then making the panel, rather than the frame, the parent of the controls?  This works better in many different ways, so I suspect it might solve your problem here.  You can set the frame transparent, but force the panel to be opaque which should cascade to all the child windows of the panel.

( I haven't tried it myself - IMHO transparent frames are ugly )

Comment: I need to implement tour like android app. I need the same thing.Could you please provide me more information.